# The Humanization of G'd, how does it happen, is He a Person?

Tags: prophecy, daniel, apocalyptic

I came with a very interesting point that said the prophet **Daniel**:

Daniel 7:9

> I was looking until thrones were set up, and the Ancient of Days sat; His raiment was as **white** as **snow**, and the **hair** of His head was like **clean** **wool**; His **throne** was sparks of fire, its wheels were a burning fire. (Chabad)

Now I want to know how is it possible for G'd to have a **white** as **snow raiment** and a **hair** as **clean wool**. Is it that these features occur to be to Him, this is, the language is godly or is it that our human language that tries to describe something that isn't possible? In other words, is it that it's G'd that truly has a hair and we don't, but since we were created in His Image, we think we truly have His features. Or is it that, it's we that have these features and think that it's the features of G'd, and to finish if there is any difference between these two options and what it would be.

In addition, I'd like to point that this happened when I saw in a book (The Book of Knowledge, chapter I) from Rambam, the **Yesodei ha Torah**, which says:

> All these [expressions were used] to relate to human thought processes
> which know only corporeal imagery, for the Torah speaks in the
> language of man.

Answer (score 2):

#### The Humanization of G'd, how does it happen, is He a Person?

Jesus' own words give us the answer when he said "God is a Spirit". ([John 4:24](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/b/r1/lp-e/nwtsty/43/4#study=discover&v=43:4:24)) As you mentioned, we are created in his image and so we could say that Jehovah God is a "spiritual" person since we have, as persons, gained his qualities. Consider too that the Almighty resides in a spiritual realm that our human minds cannot comprehend. ([Isaiah 55:9](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/b/r1/lp-e/nwtsty/23/55#study=discover&v=23:55:9))

In the topic of "[Jehovah](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/1200002391#h=55-57)" in the *Insight on the Scriptures*, we are given a more complete understanding of how and why Jehovah God is described in such ways:

> ***Descriptions of his presence.***  Since he is a Spirit beyond the power of humans to see ([Joh 4:24](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1200002391/80/0)), any description of his appearance in human terms can only approximate his incomparable glory. ([Isa 40:25, 26](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1200002391/81/0)) While not actually seeing their Creator ([Joh 1:18](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1200002391/82/0)), certain of his servants were given inspired visions of his heavenly courts. Their description of his presence portrays not only great dignity and awesome majesty but also serenity, order, beauty, and pleasantness.​—[Ex 24:9-11;](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1200002391/83/0) [Isa 6:1;](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1200002391/83/1) [Eze 1:26-28;](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1200002391/83/2) [Da 7:9;](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1200002391/83/3) [Re 4:1-3](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1200002391/83/4); see also  [Ps 96:4-6](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1200002391/84/0).
>
> As can be noted, these descriptions employ metaphors and similes, likening Jehovah’s appearance to things known to humans​—jewels, fire, rainbow. He is even described as though he had certain human features. While some scholars make a considerable issue out of what they call the anthropomorphological expressions found in the Bible​—as references to God’s “eyes,” “ears,” “face” ([1Pe 3:12](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1200002391/85/0)), “arm” ([Eze 20:33](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1200002391/86/0)), “right hand” ([Ex 15:6](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1200002391/87/0)), and so forth—​it is obvious that such expressions are necessary for the description to be humanly comprehensible. For Jehovah God to set down for us a description of himself in spirit terms would be like supplying advanced algebraic equations to persons having only the most elementary knowledge of mathematics, or trying to explain colors to a person born blind.​—[Job 37:23, 24](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1200002391/88/0).
>
> The so-called anthropomorphisms, therefore, are never to be taken literally, any more than other metaphoric references to God as a “sun,” “shield,” or “Rock.” ([Ps 84:11;](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1200002391/89/0) [De 32:4,](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1200002391/89/1) [31](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1200002391/89/2)) Jehovah’s sight ([Ge 16:13](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1200002391/90/0)), unlike that of humans, does not depend on light rays, and deeds done in utter darkness can be seen by him. ([Ps 139:1,](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1200002391/91/0) [7-12;](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1200002391/91/1) [Heb 4:13](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1200002391/91/2)) His vision can encompass all the earth ([Pr 15:3](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1200002391/92/0)), and he needs no special equipment to see the growing embryo within the human womb. ([Ps 139:15, 16](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1200002391/93/0)) Nor does his hearing depend on sound waves in an atmosphere, for he can “hear” expressions though uttered voicelessly in the heart. ([Ps  19:14](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1200002391/94/0)) Man cannot successfully measure even the vast physical universe; yet the physical heavens do not embrace or enclose the place of God’s residence, and much less does some earthly house or temple. ([1Ki 8:27;](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1200002391/95/0) [Ps 148:13](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1200002391/95/1)) Through Moses, Jehovah specifically warned the nation of Israel not to make an image of Him in the form of a male or of any kind of created thing. ([De 4:15-18](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1200002391/96/0)) So, whereas Luke’s account records Jesus’ reference to expelling demons “by means of God’s finger,” Matthew’s account shows that Jesus thereby referred to “God’s spirit,” or active force.​—[Lu 11:20;](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1200002391/97/0) [Mt 12:28](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1200002391/97/1); compare  [Jer 27:5](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1200002391/98/0)  and  [Ge 1:2](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1200002391/99/0).

[All scripture quotations from the [*New World Translation of the Holy Scriptures* (Study Edition)](https://www.jw.org/en/library/bible/study-bible/books/)]

Comment: In the beginning, man created God in his own image.

Answer (score 2):

Daniel 7 records a vision given the prophet Daniel in highly symbolic terms.  we readily see this from the what is recorded:

- a beast like a lion with eagle's wings which stands on two feet
- beast like a bear coming from the sea
- leopard with four wings and four heads
- a non-descript beast with iron teeth with 10 horns and another "little horn" that uproots three other horns
- a description of the "Ancient of Days", presumably, God the Father, with a throne flaming with fire, river of fire flowing from Him, etc.

There are clearly very symbolic images that should not be read literally true.  This is confirmed as we read:

- V23 - the fourth beast is a fourth kingdom and the other three beasts are three earlier kingdoms.
- V24 - the 10 horns are 10 kings
- the little horn is another king who is blasphemous

Thus, we cannot read this vision literally - its symbols must be interpreted as symbols of a greater reality.  Thus, God the father is represented in human terms because that is all that Daniel and his readers (including us) could understand.

Because God is Spirit (John 4:24, 2 Cor 3:18) and thus has no human form unless He decides to temporarily assume such.

Comment: So, if they could understand this way maybe we should try to litteraly use these terms, no?

Comment: @JoãoVíctorMelo - Symbols have no innate meaning except when we understand what they represent.

Comment: That's not a symbol actually, because there isn't the word "as", many scholars think it is, but when you go deeper into the books, you know it.